# Using ternary in map function to display two options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to simplify a map function, and show two options based on length of children in a data object. Basically, the function maps over the data, and if each group has more than 3 entries, show one view. If the group has fewer than 3, show a different view. I currently have it showing the view for more than 3 entries, but **can't get the ternary operator setup to show less than 3**. When I tried adding another map function, it shows the groups smaller than 3 in the middle of the others. I need to show the groups smaller than three above the ones that have more than 3.

```
{children.length > 3 &&
    children.map((item, i) => (
      <li key={i} className={classes.member}>
        <a href={`mailto:${item.email}`}>
          {item.profile ? (
            <div
              className={
                (item.lead === true && ` ${classes.profilelead}`) || ""
              }
            >
         </a>
       </li>
    ))
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've built the ternary, but having trouble rendering the groupings of less than 3 above the greater than 3

```
{children.map(
    (item, i) =>
      children.length > 3 ? (
        <li className={classes.member}>
          <a href={`mailto:${item.email}`}>
              <div
                className={
                  (item.lead === true && ` ${classes.profilelead}`) || ""}
              >
              </div>
          </a>
        </li>
      ) : (
        <p>profiles less than 3 here, but should be rendered above the greater than 3 above.</p>
      )
  )}
```

Comment: could you provide your unsuccessful `ternary operator setup to show less than 3` codes

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú - I'm having trouble getting the ternary setup, since when I move the length evaluator out of the map function, it renders `item` not defined. I'd like to have one map function, with a ternary to return items from groups larger than 3 and then another for groups smaller than 3. The smaller than 3 should render above the groupings of larger than 3.

Comment: I've figured out the ternary operator, but not sure how to render the grouping of less than 3 above the groupings of greater than 3.

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: have you tried to sort your data list first, before rendering :) It would be easier

Answer (score 0):

By sorting the children arrays object by size, I was able to arrange the grouping of less than 3 items per group at the top (or bottom if needed) like so:

```
{props.children
    .sort((a, b) => a.children.length - b.children.length)
    .map(section => <Section {...section} classes={classes} />)}
```